# What's the minimum message expansion for Digital Signature?

Tags: signature

Can we prove a minimal message expansion for a Digital Signature scheme (possibly with Message Recovery), for $b$-bit security (that is expected $O(2^b)$ work to break the system)?

Define message expansion as the maximum over all messages (perhaps at least a certain threshold $t$ in size) of the difference in size between the signed message and the original message, with the constraint that from the signed message and the public key, the public verification procedure must reconstruct the original message.

Message expansion of $2b+O(1)$ is claimed by [BLS signature](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bls-signature) with $t=0$ if I understand correctly, and reached by deterministic RSA-MR ([ISO/IEC 9796-2](https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/#iso:std:iso-iec:9796:-2:ed-3:v1:en) scheme 3) with $t=\log(N)-2b$ bit where $N$ is the public modulus, large enough to prevent factorization attack.

Comment: I don't see why 'fixed and publishing a private key' would prove that 2b is optimal, even if 2b; if someone (who knew the private key) could find two messages with the same signature in less than $O(2^b)$ time, how could that be used to break the signature (by someone who didn't know the key) is less than $O(2^b)$ time?

Comment: Also, I vaguely recall a torus-based signature system (by Alice Silverberg) that claimed to have signatures of less than 2b in length; however, it's been a long time, and a quick google didn't turn up anything...

Comment: @poncho: you are right; I removed my faulty argument that the bound can't be below $2b$ when $t=0$. I'll actively search for the Alice Silverberg signature scheme.

Comment: I think it might be https://www.math.uci.edu/~asilverb/bibliography/ceilidh.pdf ; however, the signature there doesn't appear to be as small as I remember...

Comment: I think I heard about a scheme using $1.5 n$ or $\sqrt 2 n$ once, might have been in the Multivariate-quadratic-equations category.

Comment: 'This gives an upper bound to the number of messages that may be safely signed for a given key'; I'm still missing this.  Suppose someone were to ask for the signature for two different messages from the signing oracle, and the two signatures happen to be the same; how is this inherently unsafe?  If we translate this into the Message Authentication Code arena, well, if we have a 64 bit MAC (e.g. truncated HMAC), we can find two messages with the same MAC with $2^{32}$ queries, however that doesn't break HMAC...

Comment: @poncho: you are right again; not my day :-(

Comment: From indistinguishability obfuscation you can obtain b bits (http://ia.cr/2013/454), so I guess any non-trivial lower bound would have to rule that out